# Python While Statement with greater than/less than signs

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
print ("Hello, this is a change return program, coded by A person")
cost = float(input("How much did the object cose (in £s, eg 0.50 for 50p)?"))
given = float(input("How much money did you pay (in the same format)?"))
change = given - cost
twentypounds = 0
tenpounds = 0
fivepounds = 0
twopounds = 0
onepound = 0
fiftypennies = 0
twentypennies = 0
tenpennies = 0
fivepennies = 0
twopennies = 0
onepenny = 0
print(change)
while change >= 20:
    change = change - 20
    twentypounds + 1
print(twentypounds)

while change >=10 and <20 :
    change = change - 10
    tenpounds + 1
print(tenpounds)

while change 10> and >= 5:
    change = change - 5
    fivepounds + 1
print(fivepounds)

while change <5 and >= 2:
    change = change - 2
    twopounds + 1
print(twopounds)

while change <2 and >= 1:
    change = change - 1
    onepound + 1
print(onepound)

while change <1 and >= 0.5:
    change = change - 0.5
    fiftypennies + 1
print(fiftypennies)

while change <0.5 and >= 0.2:
    change = change - 0.2
    twentypennies + 1
print(twentypennies)

while change <0.2 and >= 0.1:
    change = change - 0.1
    tenpennies + 1
print(tenpennies)

while change  <0.1 and >= 0.05:
    change = change - 0.05
    fivepennies + 1
print(fivepennies)

while change <0.05 and >= 0.02:
    change = change - 0.02
    twopennies + 1
print(twopennies)

while change <0.02 and >= 0.01:
    change = change - 0.01
    onepennies + 1
print(onepenny)


print("The Change Value is now:", change, "  This is for debugging only")
twenty_pounds = twentypounds * 20
ten_pounds = tenpounds * 10
five_pounds = fivepounds * 5
two_pounds = twopounds * 2
one_pound = onepound * 1
fifty_pennies = (fiftypennies * 50) / 100
twenty_pennies = (twentypennies * 20) / 100
ten_pennies = (tenpennies * 10) / 100
five_pennies = (fivepennies * 5) / 100
two_pennies = (twopennies * 2) / 100
one_penny = (onepenny * 1) / 100
total_change = twenty_pounds + ten_pounds + five_pounds + two_pounds + one_pound + fifty_pennies + twenty_pennies + ten_pennies + five_pennies + two_pennies + one_penny
print("Your Total Change is:", total_change)
```

This returns only 0.0 multiple times when it did work, and now gives me invalid syntax all of the time, i have tried to swap the signs around and then also the numbers but that failed to work on anything, any idea how to fix this?

---

New Code: (Still not Working, although now without syntax errors, just only returns 0 (although figures change on line 4)

```
print ("Hello, this is a change return program, coded by A person")
cost = float(input("How much did the object cose (in £s, eg 0.50 for 50p)?"))
given = float(input("How much money did you pay (in the same format)?"))
change = given - cost
twentypounds = 0
tenpounds = 0
fivepounds = 0
twopounds = 0
onepound = 0
fiftypennies = 0
twentypennies = 0
tenpennies = 0
fivepennies = 0
twopennies = 0
onepenny = 0
print(change)
while change >= 20:
    change = change - 20
    twentypounds + 1
print(twentypounds)

while change >= 10 and change < 20:
    change = change - 10
    tenpounds + 1
print(tenpounds)

while change > 10 and change >= 5:
    change = change - 5
    fivepounds + 1
print(fivepounds)

while change < 5 and change >= 2:
    change = change - 2
    twopounds + 1
print(twopounds)

while change < 2 and change >= 1:
    change = change - 1
    onepound + 1
print(onepound)

while change < 1 and change >= 0.5:
    change = change - 0.5
    fiftypennies + 1
print(fiftypennies)

while change < 0.5 and change >= 0.2:
    change = change - 0.2
    twentypennies + 1
print(twentypennies)

while change < 0.2 and change >= 0.1:
    change = change - 0.1
    tenpennies + 1
print(tenpennies)

while change  < 0.1 and change >= 0.05:
    change = change - 0.05
    fivepennies + 1
print(fivepennies)

while change < 0.05 and change >= 0.02:
    change = change - 0.02
    twopennies + 1
print(twopennies)

while change < 0.02 and change >= 0.01:
    change = change - 0.01
    onepennies + 1
print(onepenny)


print("The Change Value is now:", change, "  This is for debugging only")
twenty_pounds = twentypounds * 20
ten_pounds = tenpounds * 10
five_pounds = fivepounds * 5
two_pounds = twopounds * 2
one_pound = onepound * 1
fifty_pennies = (fiftypennies * 50) / 100
twenty_pennies = (twentypennies * 20) / 100
ten_pennies = (tenpennies * 10) / 100
five_pennies = (fivepennies * 5) / 100
two_pennies = (twopennies * 2) / 100
one_penny = (onepenny * 1) / 100
total_change = twenty_pounds + ten_pounds + five_pounds + two_pounds + one_pound + fifty_pennies + twenty_pennies + ten_pennies + five_pennies + two_pennies + one_penny
print("Your Total Change is:", total_change)
```

Now the code just prints: 
(Change is correct)
0.0,  0.0,  0.0 etc...

Code now works, thanks for your answers!

Comment: You have to repeat the variable in a condition such as `while change <0.02 and >= 0.01:` (so you need to write `while change < 0.02 and change >= 0.01`.  IIRC, you can also do: `while 0.02 > change >= 0.01:` or something similar, but you'll need to verify that.

Comment: Generally, `SyntaxError` means you skipped parts of the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html). `and <20` is not valid Python code.

Comment: Try to determine what is the problematic code and only post that in your question. This amount of code is overwhelming

Comment: The whole thing is problematic :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is with `change >=10 and <20`. This doesn't make sense because it doesn't specify what should be compared to 20. If you write out the expression fully as `change >= 10 and change < 20`, your code should function. Or, this could be written more concisely as `10 <= change < 20`.

Comment: Have now changed this, and still seems to not be working, although I no longer get a syntax error

Comment: First, there is a typo in line 69, change `onepennies` to `onepenny`. Second, the lines like `twentypounds + 1` should be `twentypounds += 1`. Third, are you using Python 2.X? If so, division doesn't work as you'd expect on integer values. For example, `5/2 -> 2` whereas `5/2.0 -> 2.5`.

Comment: Thanks, It now works, I completely forgot to put the `twentypounds += 1`

Answer (score 1):

== is a comparison
= is an assignment

You are using == in places where you should be using =

Comment: I have just edited those out, and still get syntax errors on the greater than/less than signs